# pass device token form java to js file for cordova FCM plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have used cordova FCM plugin.

I just want to pass refreshedToken value from java to my js file.

Is "sendJavascript" method is the only way to pass variable or is there any other way.

Please let me know for both the conditions.

Comment: Can anyone please answer for this...